# Timer reading when postscalar turned ON

Tags: timer, microcontroller, microchip

I have read that the postscalar of a timer specifies how many times the counter has to overflow inorder to get an interrupt.
But i have a doubt there.
So what i understand is if i put 0x55 and start timer with postscalar as 2, then timer will count from 0x55 to 0xFF and then again 0x55 to 0xFF and generate an interrupt.

Consider a case that i start the timer in an external inetrrupt. My requyirement may be to get the timegap between two interrupt. I start the timer in first interrupt, then read the timer in the next interrupt.
but if i have put postscalar then i will get the wrong time right.

I just used this as an example to make my question clear.

Edit: So will there be any issue if a timer value is read when postscalar turned ON

Usage Context: To get time difference between two interrupts

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: So will there be any issue if we read a timer with postscalar ON.  Usage Context: To find the time difference between two interrupts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. PostScale - Pre-Scale divide the clock input/output so you can sample at lower frequencies or intervals, depending on the application where you need more count than available. Let's say you have a XTAl of 8MHz with a Pre-Scaler of 1:8 (found on many PICS), you won't sample at 8MHz but at 1MHz.

Addind a pre-scaler - Post-Scaler will change the time between your 2 interrupts, surely. But that won't affect the reading of the counter value, assuming you count a variable each time there's one of the 2 interrupts on. You will simply count slower, or faster, depending on which timer you are using (most of them only have a pre-scaler option).

Comment: This is what I understand from your answer. The interrupt you mentioned is not the timer overflow interrupt. It is the interrupt for counting a timer value. Is my understanding correct.

Comment: Na it's not this. You have a 8MHz crystal. You setup Timer1 to overflow at 0xFE. At the beginning of the program, the timer start counting, until it reaches 0xFE, then raise the overflow flag. In an interrupt routine, you would lower the flag and reload 0xFE in Timer1 registers so that it restarts continuously. When you add a pre-scaler or a post-scaler, the clock at which the timer increments it's counting register is divided by the pre-scaler value, meaning it takes more time to count the same amount (0xFE).